# X11: can't set custom keyboard layout when pressing Super key

Tags: x11, bspwm, sxhkd

I want to change the default QWERTY layout to colemak layout. I use bspwm with its default sxhkd.

I tried setting it in the X11 config file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-keyboard.conf:

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "KeyboardDefaults"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    Option "XkbVariant" "colemak,"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:win_space_toggle"
EndSection
```

And it works, but when I press the Super key and the key I need (for example, d), sxhkd recognizes it as a QWERTY's g.

Also I tried setting it up on the startup of X11 in the ~/.xinitrc:

```bsh
setxkbmap -layout 'us,ru' -variant 'colemak,' -option 'grp:win_space_toggle'
```

but it doesn't work too (the same problem).

I've been using sway (a wayland wm) with this exactly settings (they made their own implementation of xkb I think) and it worked as it should. However, with standard Xorg it does not.

Answer (score -1):

It magically worked when I enabled dbus and elogind.